# How to flatten nested dataclass while serializing to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-dataclasses

I have dataclass containing other dataclass as its field:

```
@dataclass
class Bar:
    abc: int
    bed: int
    asd: int


@dataclass
class Foo:
    xy: int
    yz: Bar
```

then I try to serialize it to csv by pandas like this:

```
dataset = [Foo(xy=1, yz=Bar(abc=1, bed=2, asd=3))]
pd_dataset = pandas.DataFrame(vars(row) for row in dataset)
pd_dataset.to_csv('dataset_example.csv', index=False)
```

but the result I get is kinda different than I want to achieve. To be precise I now get:

```
xy,yz
1,"Bar(abc=1, bed=2, asd=3)"
```

and I want:

```
xy,yz_abc,yz_bed,yz_asd
1,1,2,3
```

Can you help me getting it right? I tried to write my own serialization function and do something like:
`pandas.DataFrame(asdict(row, dict_factory=row_to_dict) for row in dataset)`
but I can't get how to correctly write it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need for using an external library, Pandas provides you with everything you need in the form of [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
... from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
... 
... @dataclass
... class Bar:
...     abc: int
...     bed: int
...     asd: int
... 
... @dataclass
... class Foo:
...     xy: int
...     yz: Bar
... 
... dataset = [
...     Foo(xy=1, yz=Bar(abc=1, bed=2, asd=3)),
...     Foo(xy=10, yz=Bar(abc=10, bed=20, asd=30)),
... ]

>>> dataset
[Foo(xy=1, yz=Bar(abc=1, bed=2, asd=3)),
 Foo(xy=10, yz=Bar(abc=10, bed=20, asd=30))]

>>> df = pd.json_normalize(asdict(obj) for obj in dataset)
>>> df
   xy  yz.abc  yz.bed  yz.asd
0   1       1       2       3
1  10      10      20      30

>>> print(df.to_csv(index=False))
xy,yz.abc,yz.bed,yz.asd
1,1,2,3
10,10,20,30
```

I personally prefer the above default `"."` separator, but if you feel strongly about underscores, Pandas also got you covered:

```py
>>> pd.json_normalize((asdict(obj) for obj in dataset), sep="_")
   xy  yz_abc  yz_bed  yz_asd
0   1       1       2       3
1  10      10      20      30
```

Answer (score 2):

Carefully create desired key from `vars(Bar)` can do what you want.

```py
dataset = [Foo(xy=1, yz=Bar(abc=1, bed=2, asd=3))]

res = []

for obj in dataset:
    d = {}
    for k, v in vars(obj).items():
        if isinstance(v, Bar):
            for k_, v_ in vars(vars(obj)[k]).items():
                d[f'{k}_{k_}'] = v_
        else:
            d[k] = v
    res.append(d)

print(res)
'''
[{'xy': 1, 'yz_abc': 1, 'yz_bed': 2, 'yz_asd': 3}]
'''
```

```py
pd_dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_records(res)

print(pd_dataset)
'''
   xy  yz_abc  yz_bed  yz_asd
0   1       1       2       3
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it myself while after posting a question. To solve this problem I needed to download a library called [flatten-dict](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/). Then use it like this:

```
pd_dataset = pandas.DataFrame(flatten(asdict(row), reducer='underscore') for row in dataset)
```

If there's room for improvement to this approach let me know, but I find it really clean and simple.